# Text Box, Taking Text to the next line in a Text box

Tags: html, css

I have scanned through your vast database of question but don't seem to find an answer. I am having Problems with Take the text to a new line - even with space still left on the line before. Here is the code :

```css
p1 {
  border-left: 6px solid blue;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px 9px;
  font-size: 17px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
br {
  line-height: 200%;
}
```

```html
<br>
<p1> <b> &lt; !DOCTYPEhtml &gt; <br> &lt; html &gt; </b>
</p1>
<br>
```

Now if you were to run it, you would see something like the image below:
[image]

Now what would I have liked it to look like is something like this: 
[image]

Now this is am image of a text box under the tab Editors on the W3School Webpage. I was trying to create similar box for my website - with the Blue side line running all the way down, and with text laid out similar to the W3Schools. But I cant seem to get it right even after spending 5 hours on this very problem. Can anyone help me out?

Regards Satanshu

Comment: what kind of tag is `<p1>`?

Comment: I use different variations of the element <p> such as <p>, <p1>, <p2> etc to keep the css for each separate from each other. For Example: I set <p> to have a 6px right blue border, I may set <p1> to have a left green border 7px. I did't think that to be a problem.

Comment: you can use a class for that, not a tag, because I don't know such tags in html

Comment: So for example, <p class="textbox1">?

Comment: But even if I were to use classes, How can i solve the problem above?

Comment: yes, or set `class="p1"` and use the css you put for that tag

Comment: @SatanshuMishra That **IS** the solution., See answer.

Comment: You can't just **invent** new elements like that. That's not how HTML is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use real HTML elements.

```css
p.t1 {
  border-left: 6px solid blue;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px 9px;
  font-size: 17px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
br {
  line-height: 200%;
}
```

```html
<br>
<p class="t1"> <b> &lt; !DOCTYPEhtml &gt; <br> &lt; html &gt; </b>
</p1>
<br>
```

This works because `<p>` is a real element and `<p1>` is not.

And if you are curious to the specifics, the reason *why* `<p1>` does not work is not that it is an undefined element. (Otherwise, it wouldn't do anything; it wouldn't even have a left border on the first line.) It is because the error correction routines of your browser considers this an inline element, while `<p>` is a block element. That's really what's causing the difference in display.
Don't count on error correcting routines solving everything for you though. Sooner or later you'll run into an error that is not handled the same by all browsers, and then you'll be in trouble. Better stick to the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chris, It seemed that using tags such has  caused the text box to not work as it should. I appreciate you help mate and would look forward to returning the favor in the future.
Regards
Satanshu

Conclusion - Use classes!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.w3-code{
  line-height: 200%;
  border-left: 6px solid blue;
  padding: 10px 9px;
  font-size: 17px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
  margin:10px 5px 0 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class=w3-code>
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;<br>
&lt;html&gt;<br>
&lt;head&gt;<br>
&lt;title&gt;Page Title&lt;/title&gt;<br>
&lt;/head&gt;<br>
&lt;body&gt;<br><br>
&lt;h1&gt;This is a Heading&lt;/h1&gt;<br>
&lt;p&gt;This is a paragraph.&lt;/p&gt;<br><br>
&lt;/body&gt;<br>
&lt;/html&gt;
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

This is worked for me.